# A few bars in the wrong place in a bar graph after sorting in ascending order

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have some javascript inside a Flask application that uses d3 to render a bar graph from some randomly generated data in a specific range. It allows sorting by label or value, in ascending or descending order. Sorting works fine in every situation except specifically when sorting in ascending order by value.Most of the time, at least 2 of the bars are not in the right order.

From inspecting the code, the problem seems to be that the 'x' d3 attribute for these bars is not set correctly, so they're displayed in the wrong spot on the x axis. I figure it must be a javascript issue and not a Flask issue since the rest works but I can't seem to figure it out.

Data generation(done in Python in the original code but I generated it in js with jiphy here):

```
function data_bar_graph(num=32) {
   data_min = 0.0;
   data_max = 100.0;
   output = [];
   for (i in range(int(num))) {
        output.push(dict(label=str(uuid.uuid4())[:2],    value=random.uniform(data_min, data_max)));
    return output;

    }
}
```

The js file in question: https://jsfiddle.net/turtles_/bk3svowo/  (it doesn't work properly since I'm not sure how to pass the data or generate the graph in jsfiddle outside of flask, but you can see the code. I'll try to figure out the data passing if it's too abstract like this).

EDIT: I'm about 95% sure the error is somewhere in this following segment(only the x is sometimes wrong,rest of the values are sorted correctly so I'm thinking the .attr("x" has something weird. Does the following seem correct?

```
  data = data.sort(sortComparator);


    // Map x-axis labels
    xScale.domain(
        data.map(function(d)
        {
            return d.label;
        }
    ));
    // Map y-axis values
    yScale.domain([0, d3.max(data,
        function(d)
        {
            return d.value;
        }
    )]);

    // Draw the axes
    drawAxisLines(chart.g, xAxis, yAxis, computedHeight, 0, 0, 0);

    var bars = chart.g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "bars")
        .selectAll(".bar")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("x",
            function(d)
            {
                return xScale(d.label);
            }
        )
        .attr("y",
            function(d)
            {
                return yScale(d.value);
            }
        )
        .attr("fill",
            function(d)
            {
                return colours(d.label);
            }
        )
        .attr("height",
            function(d)
            {
                return computedHeight - yScale(d.value);
            }
        )
        .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand())
        .style(cssStyling.bar);
}
```

sortComparator is the d3.ascending/d3.descending that was mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't have a working example, it's difficult to know exactly what the issue is, but there is commonly pitfall here: you're most likely comparing the numbers as strings (e.g. `"12" < "2"`, whereas `12 > 2`).

To make sure you're comparing numbers, you can do the following:

```js
data = data.sort(function(a,b) { return d3.ascending(+a.value, +b.value); })
```

By preceding the fields with a `+`, you're coaxing those fields to numbers (which your Python code may not do automatically).